# Count Number of comment per user in my custom php website

Tags: php, mysql, database

My website is a place to write things, i mean share posts. it is a custom php development.
i Want to count the number of Comments each user in my website. 
 i have a table named `comments`
with this  structure:
id
name
date
storyid
title
content
userid
accepted

Someone can help me to find a way to count a comments for each user? in php..
Thank you guys..

Comment: which field is comment in table

Comment: using SQL COUNT and grouping by userid would seem the obvious thing to do

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
select count(comment) as comment from TABLE where user="USERNAME or ID"
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a lack of specifics in your question so I'm going to make a couple of assumptions. I'm assuming that `userID` is the user who wrote the comment and `accepted` is a boolean that we want to be true.

Your database query would look like this:

`` SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `id`) AS 'comments', `userid` FROM `comments` WHERE `accepted` = 1 GROUP BY `userid` ``

This will return a result table of two columns, the userid and the number of comments that have been accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a SQL question... try the select above.

```
SELECT userid, COUNT(*) as commentsQuantity FROM comments GROUP BY userid
```

Maybe filter the "accepted" too.

@Strawberry pointed right. I altered the SQL replacing the * with userid